# Find line number of function call from sourcing file

Tags: bash, logging, scripting

I'm trying to find a way to find out what file and line number a function was called from. The function is in a library file which is being sourced by my script.

**file1:**

```
$source file2
$warn_me "Error: You didn't do something"
```

**file2:**

```
$function warn_me() {
$  message=????
$  echo ${message}
$}
```

**Desired Output:** *$: file1:Line 2: Error: You didn't do something*

The  function call already occurs many times in many files so I'm trying to find a way to do this without changing that.

Previously the warn_me function was defined in every file that used it and this was taken care of like so:

```
$local message="$BASH_SOURCE:(""${BASH_LINENO}): ""$*"
```

Comment: See the logging and error handling implementation here: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh.  It uses BASH_SOURCE and BASH_LINENO arrays.

Comment: @codeforester - Outstanding!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for [`caller`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/caller) it seems.

```
$ cat h.sh 
#! /bin/bash
function warn_me() {
  echo "$@"
  caller 
}
$ cat g.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source h.sh
warn_me "Error: You didn't do something"
$ . g.sh
Error: You didn't do something
3 g.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up replacing the line with: 

    $local message="$BASH_SOURCE[1]:(""${BASH_LINENO}): ""$*"

Comment: Are there corner cases where `caller` is better than `BASH_SOURCE[x]`, `BASH_LINENO[x-1]` and `FUNCNAME[x]`?

Answer (score 13):

Inspired by @nosid and @Wrikken I wrote a small function to put current stack trace into a variable called $STACK. It might be useful to output to user the location some error has happened. Too bad bash does not have a built-in printStackTrace... Hope somebody could find it handy in their projects.

```
function get_stack () {
   STACK=""
   local i message="${1:-""}"
   local stack_size=${#FUNCNAME[@]}
   # to avoid noise we start with 1 to skip the get_stack function
   for (( i=1; i<$stack_size; i++ )); do
      local func="${FUNCNAME[$i]}"
      [ x$func = x ] && func=MAIN
      local linen="${BASH_LINENO[$(( i - 1 ))]}"
      local src="${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}"
      [ x"$src" = x ] && src=non_file_source

      STACK+=$'\n'"   at: "$func" "$src" "$linen
   done
   STACK="${message}${STACK}"
}
```

Update: I fixed a typo and added an error message parameter. So first parameter of the function is an error message to be added to the stack trace. btw if your script supplied on `bash`'s stdin (a bad idea in most cases), then the first position would be lost. If needed, then inthe `for` loop, change it to `i<$stack_size + 1`. But as I said, it is not good idea to feed your script to bash`s stdin, [here's why](http://rboci.blogspot.com/2011/08/devil-is-in-details-binbash.html).

Update 2: I found I have an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18873979/520567) about this. Thought to better keep updated version of the code in one place. So decided to make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/33bb2606afe1b334169dfbf202991d36). Feel free to suggest improvements to the gist. I'll try to keep this answer updated if any changes occur but I can't guarantee.

Answer (score 9):

There are three array variables that can be used for this purpose:

- `FUNCNAME`
- `BASH_SOURCE`
- `BASH_LINENO`

See the following answer for more details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707498/1305501