# Get the name of the caller script in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Let's assume I have 3 shell scripts:

**script_1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script_3.sh
```

**script_2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script_3.sh
```

the problem is that in `script_3.sh` I want to know the name of the caller script.

***so that I can respond differently to each caller I support***

*please don't assume I'm asking about `$0` cause `$0` will echo `script_3` every time no matter who is the caller*

here is an example input with expected output

- `./script_1.sh` should echo `script_1`
- `./script_2.sh` should echo `script_2`
- `./script_3.sh` should echo `user_name or root or anything to distinguish between the 3 cases`?

Is that possible? and if possible, how can it be done?

**this is going to be added to a `rm` modified script... so when I call `rm` it do something and when `git` or any other CLI tool use `rm` it is not affected by the modification**

Comment: Beware modifying the `rm` command (by giving using cover scripts called `rm`, or aliases, or functions). You'll come to rely on the functionality, and then one day you'll find yourself using the raw `rm` command without the protections, and you'll do serious damage because you've been lulled into a false sense of security.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Based on @user3100381's answer, here's a much simpler command to get the same thing which I believe should be fairly portable:

```
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o comm= $PPID)
```

Replace `comm=` with `args=` to get the full command line (command + arguments). The `=` alone is used to suppress the headers.

See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ps.html

Comment: Cygwin's `ps` does not support the `-o` option.

Comment: If the parent-name is longer than 15 chars, it gets truncated to 15 chars.... (tested on RHEL8).

Comment: @Rop This is a very standard limitation, the `comm` field is 15 char and generally just the executable name. On multi-threaded processes, it's also common for threads to change their `comm` to help differentiate between threads. The full command being invoked is usually the first argument of `args`, though using `ps` it could be difficult to separate names/paths that could contain a space form the rest of the arguments (on Linux, reading the null-terminated `/proc/self/cmdline` would be a safe way to get the full command and its arguments).

Answer (score 25):

In case you are `source`ing instead of calling/executing the script there is no new process forked and thus the solutions with `ps` won't work reliably.

Use [bash built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-caller) `caller` in that case.

```
$ cat -n server.sh 
  1  #!/bin/bash
  2  
  3  source common.sh
  4  
  5  [[ $# -ne 2 ]] && warn_me "Error: You messed up"
  6
$ cat -n common.sh 
  1  #!/bin/bash
  2  
  3  function warn_me() {
  4      echo `caller | awk '{print $2":"$1}'` says: "$@"
  5  }
  6
$ ./server.sh 
./server.sh:5 says: Error: You messed up
$
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091255/496289)

Comment: @JerryGreen it's a `bash` built-in. What shell are you using? Available at least on GNU bash.

Comment: I use standard terminal which comes with macos Catalina (10.15.7), it comes with zsh/bash/sh

Answer (score 21):

The $PPID variable holds the parent process ID.  So you could parse the output from ps to get the command.

```
#!/bin/bash
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps $PPID | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \$5}")
```

Comment: Inventive, and probably about as good as you're going to get. Not particularly nice, though.

Comment: On some platforms you just need the right options to `ps`, so the tail and Awk (which could easily be refactored to just Awk, btw) can be avoided.

Comment: this prints `/bin/bash`

Comment: @artmees Try it with `awk "{print \$6}"`

Comment: using `$6` make `./script_3` prints `'\n'` empty string and `./script_2` return `'\n./script_3'`

Comment: instead could you explain what this `ps $PPID | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \$6}"` should output and i might figure it out

Comment: @artmees I think I was looking at a modified ps, $5 is correct. You can just split the commands up to see what they do. First execute `ps $PPID`, then `ps $PPID | tail -n 1` , then add the awk. You could also add the F flag to`ps`to get command arguments, though sed of the file ps reads still feels slightly simpler.

Comment: Found another site that was recommending ps -ocommand= -p $PPID, which then removes the need for a tail command.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @J.L.answer, with more in depth explanations, that works for [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) :

```
cat /proc/$PPID/comm
```

gives you the name of the command of the parent [pid](/questions/tagged/pid)

If you prefer the command with all options, then :

```
cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline
```

### explanations :

- `$PPID` is defined by the shell, it's the [pid](/questions/tagged/pid) of the parent processes
- in `/proc/`, you have some dirs with the [pid](/questions/tagged/pid) of each process ([linux](/questions/tagged/linux)). Then, if you `cat /proc/$PPID/comm`, you echo the command name of the PID

### Check [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: this doesn't run on MacOs

Comment: on linux this is the best answer

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `cat /proc/<PID>/comm` truncates the program's name to the first 15 characters.  A least, that's the result I'm getting on the various Linux hosts I'm using.  To obtain a program name that exceeds 15 characters, I use  `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline` with additional steps to (a) strip the leading directory components from the program path string (e.g., basename(1)) and (b) strip command line arguments that follow the program name.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of useful files things kept in /proc/$PPID here

- `/proc/*some_process_id*/exe` A symlink to the last executed command under *some_process_id*
- `/proc/*some_process_id*/cmdline` A file containing the last executed command under *some_process_id* and null-byte separated arguments

So a slight simplification.

```
sed 's/\x0/ /g' "/proc/$PPID/cmdline"
```

Comment: this is not working `sed: /proc/97727/cmdline: No such file or directory`

Comment: @artmees What files do you have if you `cd` to /proc/97727? And if you don't have that, do you have any pid directories in /proc?

Comment: i don't have /proc directory

Comment: @artmees What platform are you running on?

Comment: mac osx but it needs to run on both osx and linux

Comment: @artmees Can't test it at the moment, but try `ps -Af -p $PPID | awk {'print $8'}`. I'm sure there is some location it's stored as well (you might be able to trace it out of ps), but tough to figure out without access to the system and doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: @artmees Actually don't need the A, but do need to cut header. So do `ps -f -p $PPID | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $8'}`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `/proc`:

```
$(cat /proc/$PPID/comm)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This is a UUOC. You can do a simple `$(< /proc/$PPID/comm)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the command below to avoid calling cut/awk/sed:

```
ps --no-headers -o command $PPID
```

If you only want the parent and none of the subsequent processes, you can use:

```
ps --no-headers -o command $PPID | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare this:

```
PARENT_NAME=`ps -ocomm --no-header $PPID`
```

Thus you'll get a nice variable $PARENT_NAME that holds the parent's name.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the output of `ps -o comm= $PPID` is truncated to 15 characters. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43842413/483113) the answer was

```
cut -d $'\0' -f 2 /proc/$PPID/cmdline
```

Obviously you must have `/proc` on your system. Note that the output of `ps -o args= $PPID` does **not** have `0x00` as separator.

You can then use, e.g. `basename` or `readlink -f`, to maybe add more sense to the calling filename.

Answer (score -4):

You could pass in a variable to script_3.sh to determine how to respond...

**script_1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script_3.sh script1
```

**script_2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script_3.sh script2
```

**script_3.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 'script1' ] ; then
  echo "we were called from script1!"
elsif [ $1 == 'script2' ] ; then
  echo "we were called from script2!"
fi
```

Comment: this is not possible as i'm trying add a script that handles special case of `rm` and i want it to be called if i called `rm` not if `git` used `rm` to remove some info.

Comment: please clarify your original question then, because that was not clear from your examples.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to obtain the calling program from within a bash script the way you want, I'm sorry.