# Get a string in Shell/Python using sys.argv

Tags: python, bash, shell, sys

I'm beginning with bash and I'm executing a script :

```
$ ./readtext.sh ./InputFiles/applications.txt
```

Here is my readtext.sh code :

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
counter=1
while IFS=: true; do
  line=''
  read -r line
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    break
  fi

  echo "$line"
  python3 ./download.py \
    -c ./credentials.json \
    --blobs \
    "$line"
done < "$filename"
```

I want to print the string ("./InputFiles/applications.txt") in a python file, I used `sys.argv[1]` but this line gives me -c. How can I get this string ? Thank you

Comment: Show a small snippet of what is in `./InputFiles/applications.txt ` ?

Comment: It's a text file with a list of AndroidStore applications
(com.ddd,
com....)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20572934/9035237.

Comment: Why not just pass `"$filename"` as an additional argument when you call `./download.py`? Note that the Python script should also be using `argparse` to make argument processing easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier for you to pass the parameter "$1" to the `internal` command `python3`.

If you don't want to do that, you can still get the `external` command line parameter with the *trick* of `/proc`, for example:

```
$ cat parent.sh 
#!/usr/bin/bash

python3 child.py
$ cat child.py
import os

ext = os.popen("cat /proc/" + str(os.getppid()) + "/cmdline").read()
print(ext.split('\0')[2:-1])
$ ./parent.sh aaaa bbbb
['aaaa', 'bbbb']
```

Note:

1. the shebang line in `parent.sh` is important, or you should execute `./parent.sh` with `bash`, else you will get no command line param in `ps` or `/proc/$PPID/cmdline`.
2. For the reason of `[2:-1]`: `ext.split('\0') = ['bash', './parent.sh', 'aaaa', 'bbbb', '']`, real parameter of `./parent.sh` begins at 2, ends at -1.

**Update**: Thanks to the command of @cdarke that "`/proc` is not portable", I am not sure if this way of getting command line works more portable:

```
$ cat child.py
import os

ext = os.popen("ps " + str(os.getppid()) + " | awk ' { out = \"\"; for(i = 6; i <= NF; i++) out = out$i\" \" } END { print out } ' ").read()
print(ext.split(" ")[1 : -1])
```

which still have the same output.

Comment: `/proc` is not portable.  This would work on Linux but there are many other UNIX-like systems it would not work on.

Comment: @cdarke It's a surprise for me to know `/proc` is not portable. Thank you. I tested on my Manjaro Linux before posting, however I don't know if it works on, for example OS X, after seeing your comment.

Comment: `/proc` does not exist on OS Mac (or X), it exists on SunOS but does not have the same format as on Linux, so it wouldn't work there either.  All you need do is to add the caveat "*If you are using Linux:....*"

Comment: @cdarke I am not sure if using `tail` and `awk` to find out the command line from `ps` is a more portable way, see my updated answer. Maybe the format of `ps` will hurt this one?

Comment: I factored out the `tail`. You really want to use `subprocess.run` instead of `os.popen` but this is arguably too big a change to be an edit.

Comment: @GenoChen: I would go for `psutil` module from PyPi.  That's portable, even works on Windows.  It has a function `get_process_cmdline()`.

Comment: Hi @tripleee can you please take a look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889010/get-a-string-in-shell-python-with-subprocess

Answer (score -1):

This is the python file that you can use in ur case

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]

with open(file_name,"r") as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n")

print("\n".join(data))
```

[How to use sys.argv](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

[How to use join method inside my python code](https://www.jquery-az.com/3-ways-convert-python-list-string-join-map-str/)

Comment: Downvoted: original question has already said "sys.argv[1]" is not what he need.

Comment: @GenoChen He say how he can display the strings. So I write the code for him