# Get a string in Shell/Python with subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

After this topic [Get a string in Shell/Python using sys.argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596595/get-a-string-in-shell-python-using-sys-argv?noredirect=1#comment95994052_54596595) , I need to change my code, I need to use a subprocess in a main.py with this function :

```
def download_several_apps(self):
     subproc_two = subprocess.Popen(["./readtext.sh", self.inputFileName_download], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here is my file `readtext.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash    
filename="$1"
counter=1
while IFS=: true; do
  line=''
  read -r line
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    break
  fi

  python3 ./download.py \
    -c ./credentials.json \
    --blobs \
    "$line"
done < "$filename"
```

And my `download.py` file

```
if (len(sys.argv) == 2):
    downloaded_apk_default_location = 'Downloads/'

else:
    readtextarg = os.popen("ps " + str(os.getppid()) + " | awk ' { out = \"\"; for(i = 6; i <= NF; i++) out = out$i\" \" } END { print out } ' ").read()
    textarg = readtextarg.split(" ")[1 : -1][0]
    downloaded_apk_default_location = 'Downloads/'+textarg[1:]
```

How can I get and print `self.inputFileName_download` in my download.py file ?
I used sys.argv as answerd by @tripleee in my previous post but it doesn't work as I need.

Comment: why using deprecated `os.popen` with a lot of pipes & system calls? The result will be a mix between awk, shell, python: impossible to maintain. Use pure python

Comment: in main file create a class which save all the argument for that  command/session and then share this class object to other modules. through this class object you can get the data in other modules

Comment: Either you have a lot of dead code, or you have cut out important parts. What's with the `IFS` you never use? Why do you need a subprocess at all? This seems very much like an [XY problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I changed the last line by :

```
downloaded_apk_default_location = 'Downloads/'+textarg.split("/")[-1]
```

to get the textfile name

Answer (score 0):

The shell indirection seems completely superfluous here.

```
import download

with open(self.inputFileName_download) as apks:
    for line in apks:
        if line == '\n':
            break
        blob = line.rstrip('\n')
        download.something(blob=blob, credentials='./credentials.json')
```

... where obviously I had to speculate about what the relevant function from `downloads.py` might be called.