# parent script name in sourced child

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having two scripts: parent and child.

**>>cat fake_parent.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
my_child(){
echo "I am parent "
./fake_child.sh
}
```

**>>cat fake_child.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "I am  child"
echo "I want to know my parent ...i.e fake_parent.sh here"
```

I am sourcing `fake_parent.sh` and calling `my_child` function; which should print "fake_parent.sh" at the end of the `echo` command. I have tried `$BASH_SOURCE` and `$0` but both are giving me "fake_child.sh"

Please help.

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572934/get-the-name-of-the-caller-script-in-bash-script IMHO this should be what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of the caller script in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572934/get-the-name-of-the-caller-script-in-bash-script)

Comment: @nikitaB : Why are you printing `$BASH_SOURCE ` in `fake_parent.sh` and not in `fake_child.sh`?

Comment: @ahuemmer PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o comm= $PPID) is printing "bash" and PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o args= $PPID) is printing "-bash"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# fake_parent.sh
my_child(){
echo "I am parent "
export PARENT="$(basename $0)"
./fake_child.sh
}

# fake_child.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "I am  child"
echo "I want to know my parent ... $PARENT"
```