# Does Zsh have an equivalent to BASH_LINENO?

Tags: zsh

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11090899/241142) mentions how to get the line number in a Bash function (and possibly a script as well), but I'd like to know how to do it in Zsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` just uses LINENO:

`man zshparam`:

> ```
>   LINENO <S>
>          The  line  number of the current line within the current script,
>          sourced file, or shell function being  executed,  whichever  was
>          started most recently.  Note that in the case of shell functions
>          the line number refers to the function as  it  appeared  in  the
>          original  definition,  not necessarily as displayed by the func-
>          tions builtin.
> ```

Comment: So for functions, LINENO will not display the absolute line number in the file where the function was defined, but the relative number starting from the beginning of the function. Is there a way to get, instead, the absolute line number?

Comment: @pawamoy Use `%i` for relative line number, and `%I` for absolute line number in the `PS4` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@pawamoy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837875/does-zsh-have-an-equivalent-to-bash-lineno#comment98804745_49838441), in `PS4`, use `%I` for the absolute line number.