# In Bash, is there a way to expand variables twice in double quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, parameter-passing, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

For debugging my scripts, I would like to add the internal variables $FUNCNAME and $LINENO at the beginning of each of my outputs, so I know what function and line number the output occurs on.

```
foo(){
    local bar="something"
    echo "$FUNCNAME $LINENO: I just set bar to $bar"
}
```

But since there will be many debugging outputs, it would be cleaner if I could do something like the following:

```
foo(){
    local trace='$FUNCNAME $LINENO'
    local bar="something"
    echo "$trace: I just set bar to $bar"
}
```

But the above literally outputs:
"$FUNCNAME $LINENO: I just set bar to something"
I think it does this because double quotes only expands variables inside once.

Is there a syntactically clean way to expand variables twice in the same line?

Comment: Oof. It'd be easy if you only had one variable name in your variable -- in that case it's just standard indirect expansion. By contrast, if you want to expand a template with an arbitrary number of variables, you're getting into `eval` space, which is distinctly not safe at all.

Comment: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/double-and-triple-substitution-in-bash-and-zsh) almost works - if `local trace=FUNCNAME` then you could write `echo ${!trace} ": I just set bar to $bar"`

Comment: @codeforester ...that's a pretty heavy-handed title edit. Completely removes context from the one-line summary at the top of my (original) answer, f/e, and lends itself to answers that don't address the OP's direct/immediate question about expansion *at all*.

Comment: I thought so too... Now that you are telling me, I just rolled it back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You cannot *safely* evaluate expansions twice when handling runtime data.

There are means to do re-evaluation, but they require trusting your data -- in the NSA system design sense of the word: "A trusted component is one that can break your system when it fails".

See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for a detailed discussion. Keep in mind that if you could be logging filenames, that *any character except NUL* can be present in a UNIX filename. `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.txt` is a legal name. `*` is a legal name.

#### Consider a different approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trace() { echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}: $*" >&2; }

foo() {
        bar=baz
        trace "I just set bar to $bar"
}

foo
```

...which, when run with bash 4.4.19(1)-release, emits:

```
foo:7: I just set bar to baz
```

---

Note the use of `${BASH_LINENO[0]}` and `${FUNCNAME[1]}`; this is because `BASH_LINENO` is defined as follows:

> An array variable whose members are the line numbers in source files where each corresponding member of FUNCNAME was invoked.

Thus, `FUNCNAME[0]` is `trace`, whereas `FUNCNAME[1]` is `foo`; whereas `BASH_LINENO[0]` is the line from which `trace` was called -- a line which is inside the function `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** to double expansion; but **no**, it won't do what you are hoping for.

**Yes**, bash offers a way to do "double expansion" of a variable, aka, a way to first interpret  a variable, then take that as the name of some other variable, where the other variable is what's to actually be expanded.  This is called "indirection".  With "indirection", bash allows a shell variable to reference another shell variable, with the final value coming from the referenced variable.  So, a bash variable can be passed by reference.

The syntax is just the normal braces style expansion, but with an exclamation mark prepended to the name.

```
${!VARNAME}
```

It is used like this:

```
BAR="my final value";
FOO=BAR
echo ${!FOO};
```

...which produces this output...

```
my final value
```

**No**, you can't use this mechanism to do the same as $( eval "echo $VAR1 $VAR2" ).  The result of the first interpretation must be exactly the name of a shell variable.  It does not accept a string, and does not understand the dollar sign.  So this won't work:

```
BAR="my final value";
FOO='$BAR'; # The dollar sign confuses things
echo ${!FOO}; # Fails because there is no variable named '$BAR'
```

So, it **does not** solve your ultimate quest.  None-the-less, indirection can be a powerful tool.

Comment: We have many preexisting SO questions about how to use indirection -- [Dynamic variable names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash) is perhaps the most canonical. [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is another great resource. All that said, if I had believed the OP here to be asking a question on this subject, I would have closed the question as duplicate rather than answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Although `eval` has its dangers, getting a second expansion is what it does:

```
foo(){
    local trace='$FUNCNAME $LINENO'
    local bar="something"
    eval echo "$trace: I just set bar to $bar"
}

foo
```

Gives:

```
foo 6: I just set bar to something
```

Just be careful not to `eval` anything that has come from external sources, since you could get a command injected into the string.

Comment: Not just command injection risks -- you also can't trust the log to be accurate (and thus, to be useful for debugging). If you set `bar='*'` instead of `bar=something`, the quoting won't survive through to `echo`, so you'd get a list of filenames in the log.

Comment: `eval 'echo '"$trace"'": I just set bar to $bar"'` would be safer (only expanding `$trace`, and not the rest of the string, twice), though obviously there's an ease-of-use hit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  accepted.  This use-case seemed what `eval` was originally designed for and I felt that *someone* should show it as a solution.

Comment: far worse than `"*"` is `";rm -irf /"`

Comment: I suggest that if someone could hack things to inject that command then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @cdarke, ...in a *log function*? The point of trace-level logging is (often) to show what data you're working with at runtime, to allow consideration of how a program is behaving in real-life circumstances. That data very, *very* often comes from somewhere (uploaded filenames, file content created by other tools, logs written by other processes who got the strings they substituted into those logs from who-knows-where, &c) less trusted than your code.