# How to exit shell script with exit 0

Tags: bash

I am trying to run .hql file through a shell script like below

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/

hive -f hive_script.hql
```

but the script 'hive_script.hql' is failing . I want to exit the shell script successfully even hive_script.hql script fails. Is it possible?

Comment: add this to the end of your script: `exit 0`.  But why on earth would you want to pretend the script ran successfully?

Comment: Why is this tagged `sh` though your she-bang is `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: `hive -f hive_script.hql ||:` is another idiomatic way to ignore a nonzero exit status. (`:` is another name for `true`).

Comment: BTW, it's good practice to make it `cd /path/ || exit`; without the `|| exit`, you'll try to run `hive` in the wrong directory if the `cd` fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't put an explicit `exit` in your script, the exit code of your script would be the exit code of the last command it ran - in your case, it is the `hive -f ...` command.

You can add `exit 0` at the end of your script to make sure it always exits with zero.

---

Related:

- [Raise error in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30078281/6862601)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the script to exit with 0 even when `hive -f hive_script.hql` would fail, you can just `or` the command with something that won't ever throw an error

`hive -f hive_script.hql || :`

This means that if the `hive` command fails, bash should also run the second command. In this case, that command is `:`, which is basically `pass` from python, and will always return a `0` status.

Comment: I have tried the below but it failed 
#!/bin/bash
cd /path
hive -f hive_script.hql || :

Comment: Then it is likely that you are failing before that, on the `cd /path/` part of the command. You can also do `cd /path/ || :` to prevent that from failing.

Comment: No it's not failing at that part , the .hql script is failing with "vertex failed error " . I wanted to ignore the error and exit the .sh script with success

Comment: @SanthoshChakka are you sure your script is exiting with a nonzero code? It is possible that the error message gets printed and the script still "succeeds". Does `echo $?` after running the script return a nonzero number?