# Why chain commands with "and" operator ("&&") don't stop on non-zero result with enabled "errexit"?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I have default `bash v4.4.12` set up on Debian:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I prefer to use these options in my scripts:

```
set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
```

It make stop a script on non-zero result in pipe-commands (`pipefail`), execute exit (`errexit`), and validate unset variables (`nounset`).

I have test script:

```
set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o xtrace

return_1() { return 22; }

test_1 () {
  return_1;
  echo 'after';
}

success_1() {
  echo success
}

if [ "${1:-}" == 1 ]; then
  # make "return 1" in the root level
  return_1
fi

if [ "${1:-}" == 2 ]; then
  # run test_1, we will get "return 1" within a function
  test_1
fi

if [ "${1:-}" == 3 ]; then
  # run test_1 and success_1 in chain
  # success_1 MUST NOT be ran because test_1 makes non-zero status
  # in fact, success_1 will be ran =(
  test_1 && success_1
fi
```

*Testing.*

```
$ bash /test.sh 1; echo "status: ${?}"
+ '[' 1 == 1 ']'
+ return_1
+ return 22
status: 22
```

Works as expected.

```
$ bash /test.sh 2; echo "status: ${?}"
+ '[' 2 == 1 ']'
+ '[' 2 == 2 ']'
+ test_1
+ return_1
+ return 22
status: 22
```

Everything is right. The line "echo 'after';" haven't called.

```
$ bash /test.sh 3; echo "status: ${?}"
+ '[' 3 == 1 ']'
+ '[' 3 == 2 ']'
+ '[' 3 == 3 ']'
+ test_1
+ return_1
+ return 22
+ echo after
after
+ success_1
+ echo success
success
status: 0
```

Completely NOT right. :(
1. The line "echo 'after';" *have called*.
2. The function "success_1" *have called* as well.

Really, what's going on in this case?

*UPD* Manual refferences.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've fallen into the classic trap of using `set -e`. Do carefully read through [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

From the [GNU bash documentation](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html) for `set -e`

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`

What do you think happens for this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
test -d nosuchdir && echo no dir
echo survived
```

Run it for yourself and observe why `set -e` has no effect on commands run with `&&` or `||`. The same has happened for the 3<sup>rd</sup> case you've reported. Even though the function `test_1` is returning a non-zero exit code, using another function as part of `&&` has forced the shell to ignore the `errorexit` option set.

Better to avoid `set -e` and use your own error check added. In this case use the function's return code in the if condition and negate the result

```
if ! test_1; then
    success_1
fi
```

Also read through [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30078281/5291015) which has some well written answers on how to error handling the best way in shell.

Comment: is there some best practice to handle errors at your hand? `set -o errexit` is the best for me so far.