# shell script to catch error

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have apache server which is failing several times but it is Ok. It can go to the next step. Can someone help me on how to write a shell script to catch the error, ignore it and move on to the next step.

Comment: Ignoring a failing command and continuing with the next is bash's default behavior.

Comment: Right. Unless you have `set -e` in the script, it doesn't stop when a command fails.

Comment: Take a look at this post [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30078281/6862601) that talks about error handling in detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "is failing"? Please [edit] your question and explain what is happening and what you expected to happen instead.