# How to break shell script if a script it calls produces an error

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I'm currently debugging a shell script, which acts as a master-script in a data pipeline. In order to run the pipeline, you feed a bunch of arguments into the shell script. From there, the shell script sequentially calls 6 different scripts [4 in R, 2 in Python], writes out stuff to log files, and so on. Basically, my idea is to use this script to automate a data pipeline that takes a long time to run.

Right now, if any of the individual R or Python scripts break within the shell script, it just jumps to the next script that it's supposed to call. However, running script `03.py` requires the data input to scripts `01.R` and `02.R` to be fully run and processed, otherwise 03 will produce erroneous output data which will then be written out and further processed in later scripts.

What I want to do is, 
1. Break the overall shell script if there's an error in any of the R scripts
2. Output a message telling me where this error happened [line of individual R / python script]

Here's a sample of the `master.sh` shell script which calls the individual scripts.

```
#############
# STEP 2 : RUNNING SCRIPTS 
#############

# A - 01.R 
#################################################################

# log_file - this needs to be reassigned for every individual script
log_file=01.log
current_time=$(date)
echo "Current time: $current_time"

echo "Now running script 01. Log file output being written to $log_file_dir$log_file."
Rscript 01.R -f $input_file -s $sql_db > $log_file_dir$log_file 

# current time/date
current_time=$(date)
echo "Current time: $current_time"

# B - 02.R 
#################################################################

log_file=02.log
current_time=$(date)
echo "Current time: $current_time"

echo "Now running script 02. Log file output being written to $log_file_dir$log_file"

Rscript 02.R -f $input_file -s $sql_db > $log_file_dir$log_file 

# PRINT OUT TIMINGS
current_time=$(date)
echo "Current time: $current_time"
```

This sequence is repeated throughout the `master.sh` script until script `06.R`, after which it collates some data retrieved from output files and log files, and prints them to stout.

Here's some sample output that gets printed by my current `master.sh`, which shows how the script just keeps moving even though 01.R has produced an error.

```
file: test-data/minisample.txt
There are a total of 101 elements in file.
Using the main database.
Writing log-files to this directory: log_files/minisample/.
Writing output-csv with classifications to output/minisample.csv.
Current time: Wed Nov 14 18:19:53 UTC 2018
Now running script 01. Log file output being written to log_files/minisample/01.log.
Loading required package: stringi
Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: RMySQL
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: hms
Error: The following 2 arguments need to be provided:
  -f <input file>.csv
  -s <MySQL db name>
Execution halted
Current time: Wed Nov 14 18:19:54 UTC 2018
./master.sh: line 95: -1: substring expression < 0
./master.sh: line 100: -1: substring expression < 0
./master.sh: line 104: -1: substring expression < 0
Total time taken to run script 01.R:
Average time taken per user to run script 01.R:
Total time taken to run pipeline so far [01/06]:
Average time taken per user to run pipeline so far [01/06]:
Current time: Wed Nov 14 18:19:54 UTC 2018
Now running script 02. Log file output being written to log_files/minisample/02.log
```

Seeing as the R script 01.R produces an error, I want the script master.sh to stop. But how? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: you should set errexit,  `set -o errexit` or `set -e` for short

Comment: hi - thanks for your comment. correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't that for errors produced by the shell script? i'm talking about errors in the 01.R script - the shell script master.sh isn't producing an error

Comment: Add the `master.sh` code to your question.

Comment: ok @codeforester - i'll do my best to add an illustrative snippet. sorry for the omission

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi @hek2mgl - don't see how this helps i'm afraid...

Comment: Don't post tons of code. Please take the time and create an _mcve_ as described in the link above.

Comment: @hek2mgl - ok, i updated it

Comment: Start from scratch. Create a super simple program that _just_ produces the problem and which can be run on any computer to try. Post that program here instead of your code.

Comment: Check this post: [How to raise error in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265513/6862601).

Answer (score 0):

As another user mentioned, simply running `set -e` will make your script terminate on first error. However, if you want more control, you can also check the exit status with `${?}` or simply `$?` assuming your program gives an exit code of 0 on success, and non-zero otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash
url=https://nosuchaddress1234.com/nosuchpage.html
error_file=errorFile.txt
wget ${url} 2> ${error_file}
exit_status=${?}
if [ ${exit_status} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -n "wget ${url} "
    if [ ${exit_status} -eq 4 ]; then
        echo "- Network failure."
    elif [ ${exit_status} -eq 8 ]; then
        echo "- Server issued an error response."
    else
        echo "- Other error"
    fi
    echo "See ${error_file} for more details"
    exit ${exit_status};
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to put some boilerplate at the top of most scripts like this -

```
trap 'echo >&2 "ERROR in $0 at line $LINENO, Aborting"; exit $LINENO;' ERR
set -u
```

While coding at debugging, I usually add

```
set -x
```

And a lot of trace "comments" with colons -

```
: this will parse its args but only show under set -x
```

Then the trick is to make sure any errors you know are ok are handled.
Conditionals consume the errors, so those are safe.

```
if grep foo nonexistantfile
then : do the success stuff
else : if you *want* a failout here, just call false
     false here will abort # args don't matter :)
fi
```

By the same token, if you *just* want to catch and ignore a known possible error -

```
ls $mightNotExist ||: # || says "do on fail"; : is an alias for "true"
```

Just always check your likely errors. Then the only thing that will crash your script is a *fail*.