# List all valid users under home directory

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I am on an AWS instance and have need to make a list of all the usernames on this instance. Something simple like:

`ls /home > users.txt`

would suffice, but I then need to go through each name and check its PID number, from there if the user doesn't have a PID number (ie a non zero return value) then I would like to delete it from the users text file i created.

I have tried the following, but received many errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls /home > users_inc.txt
while read line
do
    id -u $line
    if [$? -e 0]
    then
        echo $line > users.txt
    fi
done < users_inc.txt
```

Fairly new to bash scripting, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you main UID (user ID) and not PID (process ID)? If you already know which UIDs you want to delete, why bother with this loop?

Answer (score 3):

Alternate method using `awk`:

```sh
getent passwd|awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if(match($6,"/home/"$1)&&$3>=1000)print$1}'
```

- `getent passwd`: Stream accounts records database
- `awk 'awk script'`: Execute awk script to parse accounts records

The `awk` script:

```
BEGIN{
  FS=":"
}
{
  if (match($6, "/home/"$1) && $3>=1000)
    print $1
}
```

- `BEGIN{}`: Awk Initialization block executed once for the whole input stream.

  - `FS=":"`: Define `:` as the **F**ield **S**eparator
- `{}`: Main code block executed for each line or record of the input stream.

  - `if (match($6, "/home/"$1) && $3>=1000)`: If field #6 witch is the home directory path matches `/home/username` (field #1) `&&` and field #3 UID `>=` greater-than or equals to `1000` (minimum UID for normal accounts)
  - `print $1`: Then print the User Name from field #1.

Comment: That's a pretty darn clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

Modified your script, fixing the issues:

```
cd /home || { printf '%s\n' "Can't cd to /home" >&2; exit 1; }
for user in *; do
    if id -u "$user" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf '%s\n' "$user"
    fi
done > /path/to/users.txt
```

Assumed that you meant ID and not PID.

Related:

- [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/6862601)
- [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601)
- [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30078281/6862601)

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer. i made some edits to my original code and was able to get that to work instead, it just fit better with what i am trying to do.